# How can I update two rows with different where

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

I have two rows

```
Id name               value
1  close_site           1
2  close_site_message  close message
```

I want to update row 1 from close_site and change the value to 0 and update row 2 from

close_site_message and change the value to different text by one Query

Comment: what you did so far ? show some code

Comment: @ShahRukh I think that $ this-> db-> update_batch ();

Is the solution, but i did not know used

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$data = array(
  array(
  'name' => 'close_site',
  'value' => 0,
     ),
    array(
   'name'=> 'close_site_message',
  'value' => 'close message',
      )
     );

    $this->db->update_batch('table', $data, 'name');
```

Comment: didn't work its give me this error:  Error Number: 1064

Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'WHERE `value` IN (1,'different text')' Ã  la ligne 1

UPDATE `options` SET WHERE `value` IN (1,'different text')

Filename: C:\wamp\www\project\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME]
SET value = 
  CASE 
    WHEN name = 'close_site' THEN 0 
    WHEN name = 'close_site_message' THEN 'DIFFERENT_TEXT' 
    ELSE value 
  END
```